# Dynamic Width and Height to this Button

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a Button with minimal HTML/CSS. I have created the button, but I don't know how to make the width of the button dynamic. I have currently hard-coded the width (see following lines below). When I try to use `width:100p%; height:100%;`, the container dimension matches the dimensions of `.btn`. Any ideas on what I can do to fix this?

In addition, can I simplify my HTML/CSS even further? I don't think I can get rid of the `span`.

Hard coded dimensions: Lines 27-28, 34-35

My code:
https://jsfiddle.net/ye3chdr1/

Example of what I'm trying to create: https://cdn.css-tricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/css-button.png

Comment: I'm not even sure myself that gradients (in the button) can be responsive with minimal html/css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the right and the bottom position as well

```
.btn::before {
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    background: linear-gradient(#ababab, #616161);
    bottom: 5px;
    right: 5px;
}

.btn::after {
    top: 7px;
    left: 7px;
    bottom: 7px;
    right: 7px;
    background: linear-gradient(#e0e0e0, #b0b0b0);
}
```